# Transpose data from different rows to the same column, but at a regular interval, using Python (or Power Query)

Tags: python, excel, powerquery, transpose

So, I have a .xlsx dataset which I call the "source" dataset.
The "source" dataset has hundreds of lines with information about quantity of insects per species.
The header of each column of the dataset has the name of the each species.
I need to transpose this data to the same one column of another dataset, also a .xlsx file, which I call the "destiny" dataset.

I need to create a loop that does the following:

1. iterates over the column "A" of each line of the "source" dataset, starting at the cell "A2", and verify if there is data.
2. if there is data in cell "A2", copy the whole information from cell "B2" to cell "E2".
3. transpose the copied data to the "destiny" dataset at its column "C", starting at cell "C2"
4. then, in the next iteration, verify if there is data in the cell "A3" of the source dataset, and copy the whole information from cell "B3" to cell "E3"
5. then transpose the copied data to the "destiny" dataset at its column "C", but this time starting 7 cells below cell "C2", that is, transpose it at cell "C8".
6. and in the next iteration always transpose data from the "source" dataset 7 cells below the last data transposed.

I know it is a bit confusing, but with the examples below it should be clarified:

The "source" dataset looks like this:

```
Point|Spongillidae|Olindiidae|Hydridae|Oceaniidae|
:------|---------:|---------:|-------:|---------:|
 MK1   |3         |          |1       |5         |
 RT2   |2         |7         |        |          |
 GT3   |10        |1         |6       |15        |
```

The current "destiny" dataset currently looks like this:

```
Point|  Species   |Value |
:----|:----------:|-----:|
 MK1 |Spongillidae|      |
 MK1 |Olindiidae  |      |
 MK1 |Hydridae    |      |
 MK1 |Oceaniidae  |      |
 MK1 |Colletor    |TG    |
 MK1 |Habitat     |Edge  |
 RT2 |Spongillidae|      |
 RT2 |Olindiidae  |      |
 RT2 |Hydridae    |      |
 RT2 |Oceaniidae  |      |
 RT2 |Colletor    |DG    |
 RT2 |Habitat     |Riffle|
 GT3 |Spongillidae|      |
 GT3 |Olindiidae  |      |
 GT3 |Hydridae    |      |
 GT3 |Oceaniidae  |      |
 GT3 |Colletor    |JB    |
 GT3 |Habitat     |Riffle|
```

In the end, the "destiny" dataset should look like this:

```
Point|  Species   |Value |
:----|:----------:|-----:|
 MK1 |Spongillidae|3     |
 MK1 |Olindiidae  |      |
 MK1 |Hydridae    |1     |
 MK1 |Oceaniidae  |5     |
 MK1 |Colletor    |TG    |
 MK1 |Habitat     |Edge  |
 RT2 |Spongillidae|2     |
 RT2 |Olindiidae  |7     |
 RT2 |Hydridae    |      |
 RT2 |Oceaniidae  |      |
 RT2 |Colletor    |DG    |
 RT2 |Habitat     |Riffle|
 GT3 |Spongillidae|10    |
 GT3 |Olindiidae  |1     |
 GT3 |Hydridae    |6     |
 GT3 |Oceaniidae  |15    |
 GT3 |Colletor    |JB    |
 GT3 |Habitat     |Riffle|
```

I hope someone can help me to find a solution to this problem.

Comment: I wanted to present the dataset above as tables, but "Stackoverflow" saw my tables as code, and forced me to ident each line with four spaces. So, I am sorry about that.

Comment: This can be done pretty easily using Power Query. Is that an option or must you use Python?

Comment: No, Power Query would be nice to use as well. Thanks

Comment: See my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

This can also be accomplished using Power Query, available in Windows Excel 2010+ and Microsoft 365 (Windows or Mac)

To use Power Query

- Select some cell in your Data Table
- `Data => Get&Transform => from Table/Range`
- When the PQ Editor opens: `Home => Advanced Editor`
- Make note of the Table **Name** in Line 2
- Paste the M Code below in place of what you see
- Change the Table name in line 2 back to what was generated originally.
- Read the comments and explore the `Applied Steps` to understand the algorithm

***Source & Destiny***
[image]

***M Code***

```
let

//Read in Source Table
//  Change depending on your actual data source
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Source"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,
        {{"Point", type text}} & List.Transform(List.RemoveFirstN(Table.ColumnNames(Source),1), each {_, Int64.Type})), 

//Unpivot to produce a three column table
    #"Unpivot Source" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(#"Changed Type",{"Point"},"Species","Value"),

//Read in Destiny Table
//  Change depending on your actual data source
    Source2 = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Destiny"]}[Content],

//Add Index Column for Sorting
    #"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(Source2, "Index", 0, 1, Int64.Type),
    #"Destiny Typed" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Added Index",{
        {"Point", type text}, {"Species", type text},{"Value", type any}}),

//Join the two tables
    joined = Table.NestedJoin(#"Destiny Typed",
        {"Point","Species"},#"Unpivot Source",{"Point","Species"},"Join",JoinKind.FullOuter),

//Replace the null Values
    #"Replace null Values" = Table.ReplaceValue(
        joined,
        each [Value],
        each if [Value] = null then [Join][Value]{0} else [Value],
        Replacer.ReplaceValue,
        {"Value"}
    ),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Replace null Values",{"Join"}),
    #"Sorted Rows" = Table.Sort(#"Removed Columns",{{"Index", Order.Ascending}}),
    #"Removed Columns1" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Sorted Rows",{"Index"})
in
    #"Removed Columns1"
```

***Results***
[image]

***Note:*** *You could actually start with just a Source Table that included `Colletor` and `Habitat` for each **`Point`** and then generate the entire Destiny table.*

For example, if your `Source` table looks like:
[image]

Then a simple `UnPivot` would produce the `Destiny` table:

```
et

//change next line to reflect actual data source
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Source14"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,
        {{"Point", type text}, {"Colletor", type text}, {"Habitat", type text}}
        & List.Transform(List.RemoveFirstN(Table.ColumnNames(Source),3), each {_, Int64.Type})),

//Unpivot all except the Point Column
    #"Unpivoted Other Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(#"Changed Type", {"Point"}, "Attribute", "Value")
in
    #"Unpivoted Other Columns"
```

Producing=>
[image]

If this is something feasible, the code could easily be modified to include the "blank" entries as well as the desired sort order.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure your initial data starts from the upper left corner of Sheet1 (A1="Point").

Create a macro in Excel and name it i.e. Sub change_format() and paste the following code between "Sub change_format()" and "End sub". Then run it and you will get the results in Sheet2. Make sure to save your file in .xlsm format!!

```
i = 1 'First row of Sheet1 for reading
r = 2 'First row of Sheet2 for writing
   
'Find number of Points

While Sheet1.Cells(i, 1) <> ""
    
    i = i + 1

Wend

pnt = i - 2

For p = 1 To pnt 'Points
    For s = 2 To 7 'Species
                 
    cur_type = Sheet1.Cells(p + 1, 1) 'Current type
    cur_spc = Sheet1.Cells(1, s)      'Current species
    cur_val = Sheet1.Cells(p + 1, s)  'Current value
    
    Sheet2.Cells(1, 1) = "Point"
    Sheet2.Cells(1, 2) = "Species"
    Sheet2.Cells(1, 3) = "Value"

    Sheet2.Cells(r, 1) = cur_type
    Sheet2.Cells(r, 2) = cur_spc
    Sheet2.Cells(r, 3) = cur_val
    r = r + 1
    
    Next s
    
Next p
```